# How to identify and recover RAID on 2 drives?

Tags: partitioning, raid, data-recovery

I have 2 drives from my older PC. They are a RAID setup, but I don't remember which type.

One of the drives shows up in Windows as having a partition table, but the partitions themselves are not accessible.

I'd like to minimize the risk of losing data on these drives. What's the best course of action to take? A solution that can be applied either on Windows or on Linux would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are only 2 drives, then it was either a raid 0 stripe or raid 1 mirror.  Since the drives aren't readable independently, it has to be a raid 0 stripe.  The problem is that you probably set it up using hardware raid - which requires the original controller - so they have to be back in the original machine to be readable unless you can get the same controller in a new machine.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. Thank you, I'll try them in the old PC then.